# ROS Bridge Server

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

I am an intern in charge of improving the gazebo simulation for my internship. Currently, I managed to successfully drive my virtual buggy in the gazebo world smoothly as shown in the video link.

https://youtu.be/uS5PXshZZTU

Right now, I am tasked by my supervisor to connect my virtual buggy's movements to the movement of the real buggy that we have, so for example, when the real buggy moves 1 metre, the virtual buggy also moves 1 metre in its virtual world. I was told to use ROS Bridge Server to do this task but I do not have an idea on how to start this task at all. So I would appreciate it if someone who is knowledgable in this area help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly, it is really simple to change from simulation to real world application. The most ROS driver for robots have the roslaunch flag simulation and setting it on false causes ROS to launch the real controllers to.

I do not know if you created your gazebo package from scratch but if not there must be a possibility to launch the launch file with a `sim:=false` flag. Look into thr rviz support and in the demo.launch file.

Comment: Do you have any video tutorials that can guide me to do this rosbridge server?

Comment: If you do have a running ROS System on both Machines I think you do not need a rosbridge server...

Comment: Then in that case how do I connect my virtual buggy with the physical buggy without using rosbridge server, i have ros system running on both machines

Comment: Basically, you should have a planning system in your buggy control. This planning system publishes in most cases the new velocities and positions of the robot. The virtual buggy only subscribes these parameters and simulates a real buggy according to these values. The real buggy only needs to subscribe to the same topic to execute the commands in the real world. For this the most ROS systems do have given files and packages. The launch file mostly named buggy_robot.launch or similar. See the package of the turtlebot which does the above described.

Comment: https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/tree/master/turtlebot3_bringup ... Here the link to the package. Hope it will help you.